# npm install error for bitly

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install a bitly node module for shortening a url by using the following command

```
sudo npm install bitly --save
```

and getting the following error --

```
npm ERR! path /var/www/frontend/node_modules/request/node_modules/.bin/uuid
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /var/www/frontend/node_modules/request/node_modules/.bin/uuid: is outside /var/www/frontend/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /var/www/frontend/node_modules/request/node_modules/.bin/uuid
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.